# lodash Is There a "Between" function in lodash for comparing dates?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I've been doing lots of searching. Unfortunately I didn't come to anything useful, is there a function in lodash "between"?

I'm using moment to get dates:

- Today
- Last week

Please find the code snippet below:

```
let today = moment().format().toString();
let lastWeek = moment().isoWeekday("Sunday").subtract('days', 7).format().toString();
```

I have a list of dates and I wanted to get the dates between last week and today. I've used lodash _.filter()

```
let datesBetweenLastWeekAndToday = _.filter(datesList, (date) => {
      return date == today;
});
```

I know this is not correct, this returns only the items in the date list equals to today only. How can I make it return a list for dates between last week and today?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: If you are using moment, why do you wish to use lodash to compare dates? Lodash has `isBefore` and `isAfter` functions

Comment: `moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25')`

Comment: Actually no I don't have to use lodash. Its just that i had an array and i thought lodash was the best library when working with arrays, but any other solution is more than welcome ofcourse.

Comment: You don't need lodash for this. In this case JS [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and moment's [`.isBetween()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) will be enough.

Comment: Thank you guys, Worked!! :)